# Error while converting json to csv using csvkit

Tags: python, json, csv, csvkit

Hi i downloaded a csvkit to my macbook everything went well by following the tutorial [enter link description here](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/install.html) however when i tried to convert the json files using this command

```
in2csv customers-page-1.json > customers-page-1.csv
```

**This is the error**

```
When converting a JSON document with a top-level dictionary element, a key must be specified.
```

I dont know what to put the or where to put the key as spcified by the error heres my json files

```
{

"page":1,
"pages":132,
"count":5945,
"items":[
    {
        "id":74798241,
        "firstName":"Edyth",
        "lastName":"U.",
        "fullName":"Edyth U.",
        "photoUrl":null,
        "photoType":null,
        "gender":"unknown",
        "age":null,
        "organization":null,
        "jobTitle":null,
        "location":null,
        "createdAt":"2016-03-02T04:26:52Z",
        "modifiedAt":"2016-03-02T04:26:52Z"
    }]}
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/issues/361) already? (concerns the error you're seeing)

Comment: yeah i did it does not say anyting there where to put the key

Comment: by the way i could easily convert it with online json converter but i have thousand of json files it takes me forever to convert if i have to do it there

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the key under which there is a list objects to make into the rows of CSV. In this particular case, `items`:

```
in2csv -k items test.json
```

As a general hint, if you run a command without arguments, you will get short usage, and longer with `--help` switch:

```
% in2csv
usage: in2csv [-h] [-d DELIMITER] [-t] [-q QUOTECHAR] [-u {0,1,2,3}] [-b]
              [-p ESCAPECHAR] [-z MAXFIELDSIZE] [-e ENCODING] [-S] [-H] [-v]
              [-l] [--zero] [-f FILETYPE] [-s SCHEMA] [-k KEY] [-y SNIFFLIMIT]
              [--sheet SHEET] [--no-inference]
              [FILE]
in2csv: error: You must specify a format when providing data via STDIN (pipe).
```

and

```
% in2csv --help
usage: in2csv [-h] [-d DELIMITER] [-t] [-q QUOTECHAR] [-u {0,1,2,3}] [-b]
              [-p ESCAPECHAR] [-z MAXFIELDSIZE] [-e ENCODING] [-S] [-H] [-v]
              [-l] [--zero] [-f FILETYPE] [-s SCHEMA] [-k KEY] [-y SNIFFLIMIT]
              [--sheet SHEET] [--no-inference]
              [FILE]

Convert common, but less awesome, tabular data formats to CSV.
....
  -k KEY, --key KEY     Specifies a top-level key to use look within for a
                        list of objects to be converted when processing JSON.
```

Comment: yes i know thats the key however i dont know where to put that key inside this command 
`in2csv customers-page-1.json > customers-page-1.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Calling the program like so:

```
$ in2csv --key items customers-page-1.json > customer.csv
```

Produces:

```
$ cat customer.csv 
id,firstName,lastName,fullName,photoUrl,photoType,gender,age,organization,jobTitle,location,createdAt,modifiedAt
74798241,Edyth,U.,Edyth U.,,,unknown,,,,,2016-03-02T04:26:52Z,2016-03-02T04:26:52Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive got the answer heres the code

```
in2csv -k items customers-page-1.json > customers-page-1.csv
```

where **items** is the **KEY**